# Networkx plot gets cut off in heroku

Tags: python, matplotlib, heroku, networkx

So I have deployed a django app on heroku. It creates a networkx graph.
This function basically does the drawing and returns the base64 image.

```
    def draw(self, plot=False):
        self.compile() # creates the self.graph using list of edges
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4.5))
        nx.draw_networkx(self.graph,
                         pos=self.pos,
                         node_color=self.node_color,
                         node_size=self.node_size,
                         edgecolors=self.edgecolors,
                         edge_color=self.edge_color,
                         width=1.5,
                         ax=ax)

        ax.set_xlim([2 * x for x in ax.get_xlim()])
        ax.set_ylim([2 * y for y in ax.get_ylim()])
        if plot:
            plt.show()
            
        buffer = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buffer, format='png', bbox_inches="tight")
        plt.close()
        img64 = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")
        return img64
```

The Html snippet

```
<div id="section2" class="section">
    <div id="table_div" class="row">
        <div class="col s12 center-align">
            <!--- TABLE TEMPLATE -->
            {% if image != None %}
                <div class="card-panel">
                <img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ image }}"\>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I run this locally the graph drawing works completely fine.
[image]

However, when I deploy this to heroku, I get a cropped image
[image]

So what's exactly going wrong here ? (how do I make sure the figure doesn't get cropped)

feel free to check out the problem directly https://ongko.herokuapp.com/appdata/applet/Graph/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a graphviz problem. 'neato' `nx.drawing.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(self.graph, prog='neato')` is not working correctly for some reason, I substituted it with `nx.drawing.layout.spring_layout(self.graph)` and things are working out as expected.